# Как правильно внести изменения в файл конфигурации приложения на php используя ansible?

Tags: php, ansible, ansible-playbook

Как правильно внести изменения в файл конфигурации приложения на php используя ansible?

1. Исходные данные:

```yml
vars:
    ips:
        - 192.168.0.1
        - 192.168.0.4
        - 192.168.0.7
```

2. Файл конфигурации `config.php`:

```php
return [
    'ips': [
        '192.168.0.1',
        '192.168.0.2',
        '192.168.0.3',
        '192.168.0.4',
        '192.168.0.5',
    ]
]
```

3. Нужно обновить файл конфигурации `config.php` из п.2 в соответствие с исходными данными из п.1 и привести его к виду:

```php
return [
    'ips': [
        '192.168.0.1',
        '192.168.0.4',
        '192.168.0.7',
    ]
]
```

Comment: п3 - это прям содержимое файла? Прям если блокнотом открыть - он прям так будет выглядеть как ты написал?

Comment: верно, это то каким должен стать файл из п2, на основании данных из п1 (нужно удалить лишние адреса, добавить новые или просто заменить часть содержимого со списком адресов)

Comment: А это точно json? У меня https://json2yaml.com/ ругается на синтаксис. Может всё-таки `{"return":{"ips":["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.4","192.168.0.7"]}}` ?

Comment: это не json, это пхпешный array, эти файлы с расширением .php (вот пытаюсь понять есть ли решение кроме регулярок как с этими файлами работать, на редите подсказали в сторону Jinja template смотреть)

Comment: Внутри файла кроме твоего текста ещё чё-то есть? Или то, что ты запостил - единственное содержимое?

Comment: Это упрощенный кусок, может содержать и другие данные, нужно обновлять адреса с привязкой к названию ips

Comment: Ок. 3 строчки в начале - это отдельный файл или vars, который приезжает в ансибл из другого места?

Comment: это можно упростить на этом примере, пусть vars будет

Comment: если можно административно сказать "этот файл безусловно будет перезаписан из ansible" - запихиваете его как шаблон (action template) в ansible. Если нельзя - рефакторите свой config.php чтобы можно было. Например, вынести список ip из config.php в другой файлик. Тогда переписываете ансиблом этот самый другой файлик.

Answer (score 1):

Плейбук будет выглядеть примерно так:

```yaml
---
  - name: Create php config
    hosts: all
    strategy: free
    serial:
      - "100%"
    vars:
      ips:
        - 192.168.0.1
        - 192.168.0.4
        - 192.168.0.7
    tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/php_array.php
        content: |
          return [
              'ips': {{ ips | to_json }}
          ]
        backup: yes
```

Если менять только часть, а не весь файл менять, то модуль `copy` меняем на модуль `blockinfile`.

В пхп не умею, так что негде проверить на сколько валидно там скобки/запятые расставились. Я бы на вашем месте данные бы хранил/передавал всё-таки в json. Тем более конфиги.

UPD. Пример таски с `blockinfile`

```yaml
- blockinfile:
    path: /tmp/php_array.php
    block: |
      return [
          'ips': {{ ips | to_json }}
      ]
    backup: yes
```

Не, если 2 таски делают каждый раз противоположные действия - то идемпотентность теряется. Это противоречит концепции системам контроля конфигурации.

Comment: Ок понял, полное копирование не совсем подходит т.к. мне нужно заменить часть файла, но в любом случае спасибо, теперь понятна разница, когда использоваться модуль copy, а когда blockinfile. Если возможно просьба хотя бы примерный конфиг модуля blockinfile для моего случая.

Comment: Все примеры, что вижу на оф сайте вставляют новый текст в какую то позицию, но мне нужно не просто вставить, а привести в соответствие, видимо, надо два   task, первый удаляет старое, второй добавляет новое ...

Comment: Но тогда он будет каждый раз это делать, даже в случае если обновление не требуется ...

Comment: Ну я бы на твоём месте переписал бы это всё в json. Ну или кто там у вас это всё прогает. Конфиг на пхп - это фиговая практика. Данные не должны быть в формате какого-либо языка программирования. Потому что как только понадобится расширяемость (а добавление настройки через ansible - отличное тому потверждение) - начинаются проблемы. А потом вам понадобится через powershell дёргать данные и чё? Пишем парсер на павершелле?

Comment: @5f0f5, если ответ правильный - отметь галкой.